Can PDA sign TXs from the client, not via invoke_signed?
I'm a beginner in Rust & Solana. Currently trying to create OpenBook -> migrate a token to a Raydium.
Problem: migration_vault which stores all liquidity for migration is PDA. I need to create multiple accounts for OpenBook, but some of them are 10kb+ in size, so I cannot do that inside a Solana program. The solution - do this through the client, but fees for account creation must be covered via migration_vault (PDA). And based on what I found I cannot sign via PDA inside the app (client), only through invoke_signed in the Solana program.
How it can be potentially resolved? migration_vault must pay all fees
pub fn create_openbook_market(ctx: Context<CreateOpenBookMarket>) -> Result<()> {
    msg!("Starting OpenBook market initialization...");
 
    let bonding_key = ctx.accounts.bonding_curve.key();
    let seeds = &[
        b"migration_vault",
        bonding_key.as_ref(), 
        &[ctx.bumps.migration_vault]
    ];
 
    msg!("Creating market account...");
    let create_market_ix = system_instruction::create_account_with_seed(
        &ctx.accounts.migration_vault.key(),
        &ctx.accounts.market.key(),
        &ctx.accounts.migration_vault.key(),
        "market",
        ctx.accounts.rent.minimum_balance(OpenBookStateSize::MARKET as usize),
        OpenBookStateSize::MARKET,
        &ctx.accounts.openbook_program.key()
    );
 
    msg!("Creating market account TX...");
    solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
        &create_market_ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.migration_vault.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.market.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
        &[seeds]
    )?;
 
    let params = MarketInitParams {
        vault_signer_nonce: 0,
        coin_lot_size: 100_000,     
        pc_lot_size: 1,             
        pc_dust_threshold: 1,        
        fee_rate_bps: 0,           
    };
    
    let mut data = vec![0u8]; // initialize_market discriminator
    params.serialize(&mut data).map_err(|_| ErrorCode::SerializationError)?;
    
    msg!("init market...");
    let init_market_ix = Instruction {
        program_id: ctx.accounts.openbook_program.key(),
        accounts: vec![
            AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.market.key(), false),
            AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.request_queue.key(), false),
            AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.event_queue.key(), false),
            AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.bids.key(), false),
            AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.asks.key(), false),
            AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.base_vault.key(), false),
            AccountMeta::new(ctx.accounts.quote_vault.key(), false),
            AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.coin_mint.key(), false),
            AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.pc_mint.key(), false),
            AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.migration_vault.key(), true),
            AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.token_program.key(), false),
            AccountMeta::new_readonly(ctx.accounts.rent.key(), false),
        ],
        data,
     };

    msg!("init market TX...");
    solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
        &init_market_ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.market.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.coin_mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.pc_mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.migration_vault.to_account_info(),
        ],
        &[seeds]
    )?;
 
    msg!("✅ OpenBook market initialized successfully");
    Ok(())
}

This is how I'm trying to do that, but it doesn't work due to a problem described above.

You cannot sign with PDA in client side because PDAs are program derived offcurve addresses, which it does not have private keys. You cannot sign transaction in client side without private keys, but only the program which derived the PDA can sign with it.
